# How can I change the default URL of ActiveAdmin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

By default, ActiveAdmin is running under /admin. Is there any way change that?

Comment: See if this helps at all: https://github.com/gregbell/active_admin/blob/master/docs/1-general-configuration.md#namespaces

Answer (score 34):

Yes. You need to add the following line to the `config/initializers/active_admin.rb` file:

```
config.default_namespace = :your_desired_namespace
```

This will create a `http://yourdomain.name/your_desired_namespace`

Do note, that you will need to update your routes accordingly (i.e `admin_user_path` will become `your_desired_namespace_user_path`).

Answer (score 16):

Alternatively to @Amir answer. If you don't care about the exact path, and just want to change the route to something less obvious without needing to change your routes. On the routes file you can just call ActiveAdmin like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope 'something-else' do
    ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
    get '/', to: 'admin/dashboard#index'
  end
end
```

Then your routes would be `/something-else/admin` and you could access the dashboard on `/something-else`.

And you could still use the regular helpers like `admin_user_path`.

Answer (score 5):

Just for further reference, if you want to run ActiveAdmin from the root path as a standalone app, use this:

```
config.default_namespace = false
```